# Internet keeps timing out on Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I have really strange WiFi issues on my early 2015 MBP. I'm running Yosemite 10.10.5 and for some strange reason wifi/internet stops working for up to a minute and then starts working again. In the meantime I am not disconnected. I say wifi/internet because I'm not sure where the root cause is. All my other equipment still works when my MBP decides to stop working. Even my old 2009 MBP still works fine when my MBP drops out. Since I haven no clue where to start looking to fix this problem, I was hoping to find some guidance here.

Comment: One thing to try: in System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced..., delete _all_ the Preferred Networks and recreate the one you connect to most often. If you don't want to be so drastic, then make sure the wifi network you need is at the top of the Preferred Networks list. If the network in question is the only wi-fi network, tear it down and start again.

Comment: Seems like another Yosemite bug... I have the same issue since the 10.10.5 udpate.

Answer (score 1):

It was a strange issue with my configuration as far as I know. I ended up simply moving `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/` to another location (or just renaming/deleting) and rebooting my MBP. Everything has worked fine ever since.

Answer (score -1):

Try rebooting the gateway. Type 192.168.0.1 in any search bar and look for an option that says "Reboot/restart router". Click it. Wait a while, then see if your internet connection is faulty. If it is, check your wi-fi card, or try upgrading to OS 10.11 El Capitan, maybe this will fix any bugs in your system. If not, success!